# Question on proof regarding orthogonal projections onto spans

Tags: linear-algebra

a bit stuck on this question:

Let $U$ be the span of $k$ vectors, $\{u_1, ... ,u_k\}$ and $Pu$ be the orthogonal projection onto $U$. 
Let $V$ be the span of $l$ vectors, $\{v_1, ... v_l\}$ and $Pv$ be the orthogonal projection onto $V$. 
Let $X$ be the span of $\{u_1, ..., u_k, v_1, ... v_l\}$ and $Px$ be the orthogonal projection onto $X$.

Show $Px*y = Pu*y + Pv*y$ if and only if the space U is orthogonal to the space V (for all $y$ in $R^n$).

I'm having trouble on both sides of this if and only if proof. Any help? thanks.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and show what you've tried?

Comment: I'm actually pretty lost, to be honest. In the backwards direction, if U is orthogonal to V, then Pu is orthogonal to Pv, and I'm assuming Puy is orthogonal to Pvy? (That might be wrong - what does Puy and Pvy mean? is y a vector?) Pxy would therefore be the sum of Puy and Pvy because? Really not sure if that is a valid proof for this direction... confused. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one direction, if $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal then $\{u_1,\ldots, u_k,v_1,\ldots v_l\}$ is a linearly independent set, which implies $X=U\oplus V$, so any element of $x\in X$ may be written uniquely as $x=u+v$ with $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, i.e., $x=P_U(x)+P_V(x)$.

Comment: thank you so much. Quick question. When you wrote "x=PU(x)+PV(x)" did you mean Px=Pu(x)+Pv(x)? Also, was the implied step that X(x) = U(x) + V(x) therefore Pux = Pu(x) + Pv(x)

Comment: Yes, my notation was slightly different than yours. I don't understand what you mean in your last sentence. Also, if you find an answer helpful, you should up-vote it by clicking on the arrows pointing upward to the left of the answer.

Comment: thanks. do you have any idea how to do the other direction (forward)? I'm not sure what  Px∗y=Pu∗y+Pv∗y would suggest that would lead to me to the fact that U is orthgonal to V...